# Does my Arm Quad processor have 4 Neon Register and can they work in parallel

Tags: c++, assembly, arm, computer-vision, raspberry-pi3

Hey so I have a Raspberry Pi 3 which comes with an  ARM Cortex-A53 processor . And I do some Imageprocessing on it. I'm planing to do parallel processing using TBB and using the Neon register. Now my question is if I have 4 independent Neon Register which can work in parallel.

Comment: It has 4 independent CPU's that mostly work independently. They have independent cache memory and shared cache memory. They also have a single SDRAM memory bus. Running 4 threads (1 on each CPU) doing memory-intensive work will not yield 4x the performance. To answer your question...yes, you have 4 independent sets of registers because there are 4 independent CPUs

Comment: Do you have a 64-bit OS running on your Pi3?  If so, which one?

Comment: I'm looking for one too. If you find a working one which supports camera tell me. But for neon itself you don't need aarch64

Comment: @InfinitelyManic Don't know if possible to write messages. So I write you over here. Only trace on 64bit I found was this one
https://www.kraxel.org/blog/2016/04/fedora-on-raspberry-pi-updates/

Comment: @FelixYahBattaMan - Thanks. I was curious. I only have the Pi3 but I do have a PINE64+ which I use to explore ARMv8.